# Ionic 5 Result can't show in console log

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

**It can't show in console log, but I can run pass in ionic version 3 or 4.  Now I use Ionic 5.**

I can't get the point from select in radio. I don't know what wrong when run it's not show any problem.

> in file html

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor = "let q of Questionlist ; let i = index" >
    <p>{{ q.qname }}</p>

    <ion-radio-group>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item text-wrap >
            <ion-radio mode="md" value={{q.ansp}} (ionSelect)="mcqAnswer(q.ansp,i)"></ion-radio>
            <ion-label> {{q.ans }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col>
          <ion-item text-wrap>
            <ion-radio mode="md" value={{q.ans1p}} (ionSelect)="mcqAnswer(q.ans1p,i)" ></ion-radio>
            <ion-label>{{q.ans1 }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col>
          <ion-item text-wrap>
            <ion-radio mode="md" value = {{q.ans2p}} (ionSelect)="mcqAnswer(q.ans2p,i)"></ion-radio>
            <ion-label class=  "text-wrap">{{ q.ans2 }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col>
          <ion-item text-wrap>
            <ion-radio mode="md" value={{q.ans3p}} (ionSelect)="mcqAnswer(q.ans3p,i)"></ion-radio>
            <ion-label>{{q.ans3 }}</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-item-sliding>
  </div>
```

> in file ts

```
mcqAnswer(value, index) {
    let anws = { p: value, i: index }

    if (this.anwsList[index] !== undefined && index == this.anwsList[index].i) {
      this.anwsList[index].p = value
    } else {
      this.anwsList.push(anws)
    }

    console.log("=>", value, "=>", index)
    console.log("===>", this.anwsList)

  }
```

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the value of the selected radio button you must use the ionChange event in the ion-radio-group tag.
then you have to pass the $event as a function argument to the .ts file.
I recommend you to log it in the console to see what happens.
I hope it helps.